# Replace javascript special characters appearing in particular order

Tags: javascript, replace

I am looking to turn a string like

> ["[\"232323232\"]","909090909"]

into

> ["232323232","909090909"]

that is replacing all the special characters (but not the double quotes and comma in the outermost square brackets) with empty spaces.

I have tried this combination `.replace(/[^0-9\.,]/g, "")` without success. Thanks for your help !

Comment: _all the special characters_, then do you have another example with some of those special characters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex that try both cases you want to substitute:

```
/"\[\\|\\"]/
```

[See the live example](https://regex101.com/r/481zVe/1)

Comment: he's asking for all special characters.

Comment: Thank you guys, it worked. Great to discover that regex website too, it will help me a lot.